# Bootstrap responsive fix on small tablet & phones

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap 2.2.2 and have the following html markup.

```
<div class="container">
      <h1>Responsive boxes</h1>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
          <h3>M. 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
          <h3>M. 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
          <h3>M. 3</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
          <h3>M. 4</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
```

and css markup as follow:

```
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Cabin', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Lobster', Georgia, Times, serif;
}

h3{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 139px;
  line-height: 171px;
}

.span3 {
  background: rgb(255, 81, 10);
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

This markup works fine on desktop, when I resize the viewport (e.g. iphone) boxes are smaller as expected, but right margin becomes removed. There is only left margin. I want the left and right margin to be aligned.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/BkNSL/

I commented out the width in your body css

```
body {
background-color: #fff;
font-family: 'Cabin', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
/* width: 100%;*/
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Took me a while to spot the easy solution ... less is definitely more in this case ;)